# Task Parallel library and Trace Listeners trace listneerns not being called

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, trace

So I have a loop of tasks, everything works and logs correctly

But after I put a `Parallel.ForEach` around it, my logging is broken.

I have a custom trace listener, that takes the trace message and puts in int a buffer that is processed else were as well as being logged.

after going parallel the trace listener is no longer called.
(output line is a wrapper around Trace.WriteLine, and the trace and flush stuff is added to try to pin down the issue. Trace.AutoFlush already = true...)

code as of test in comments

```
Parallel.ForEach( allStudentsInAd, ( StudentPortalNightly.CV.AllAdStudentsCV adStudent )  =>
{
    OutputLine( "*********before" );
    //AddUserToListIfNotCorrectlyTied( allStudentsInCdssDict, studentsAlreadyTiedDict, adStudent, ref cachedAllStudentsToBeTied, ref allStudentsInAd );
    OutputLine( "*********after" );
    Trace.Flush();
});
```

code before parallelization per request (it's a foreach)

```
        foreach ( StudentPortalNightly.CV.AllAdStudentsCV adStudent in allStudentsInAd )
        {
            AddUserToListIfNotCorrectlyTied( allStudentsInCdssDict, studentsAlreadyTiedDict, adStudent, ref cachedAllStudentsToBeTied, ref allStudentsInAd );
        }
```

listener

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using JCDCHelper.Extension;
using JCDCHelper.Logging.Interfaces;
using JCDCHelper.Utilities.Interfaces;
using StructureMap;

namespace StudentPortalNightly.Utilities
{
    public class SpnCustomListener:TextWriterTraceListener
    {
        private INetLog log = ObjectFactory.GetInstance< INetLog >();

        private Object slLock = new Object();

        private List < string > sl = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the string list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_sl">The _SL.</param>
        public void SetStringList( List<string> _sl )
        {
            sl = _sl;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the string list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<string> GetStringList()
        {
            return sl;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SpnCustomListener"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public SpnCustomListener()
        {
            base.Name = "TraceOutputCustom.txt";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes the value of the object's <see cref="M:System.Object.ToString"/> method to the listener you create when you implement the <see cref="T:System.Diagnostics.TraceListener"/> class, followed by a line terminator.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">An <see cref="T:System.Object"/> whose fully qualified class name you want to write.</param>
        public override void WriteLine( object o )
        {
            WriteLine( o == null ? "" : o.ToString() );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes a message to this instance's <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.Writer"/> followed by a line terminator. The default line terminator is a carriage return followed by a line feed (\r\n).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">A message to write.</param>
        /// <PermissionSet>
        ///     <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/>
        /// </PermissionSet>
        public override void WriteLine( string message )
        {
            log.Debug("WriteLine()..."+ message );
            message = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + message;
            //base.Write( " " );
            base.WriteLine( message );

            if ( null != sl )
            {
                lock( slLock )
                {
                    sl.Add( message );
                }
                Console.WriteLine( message );// so it will log in console mode too - EWB
            }
            else
            {
                log.Debug( "SpnCustomListener string buffer is null" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are they all being created as Threadlocal?

what do I need to do to get the individual threads to log to the trace listener?

Comment: Please could you post the code before you parallelise it (for comparison)?

Comment: Uhh.. it's a foreach, but sure, that has been added.

Comment: Neither `Parallel.ForEach` or the `foreach` appear to call `SpnCustomListener`. Where is `OutputLine` coming from and what's the definition of `AddUserToListIfNotCorrectlyTied`?

Comment: I hope you did not forget to change your  collections into concurrent collections or thought about locking..... Concurrent calls to standard collections will get you into trouble.

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal - yeah, I’d seen the same thing as JSteward  and wanted to see if you’d left something out on the change to Parallel.  If they’re the same and it worked before, then I assume we’re missing a link somewhere

Comment: I changed the current sample by removing the call to AddUserToListIfNotCorrectlyTied, the out put now is the begin line shows up , and then nothing....

I have locks around the list.add in the CustmoListener... that's all that's going on.

Comment: Do you use Console.ReadKey () in your code. If so you may want to look at http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dorony/2012/09/12/consolereadkey-net-45-changes-may-deadlock-your-system/

Comment: Nope thanks though, this process runs without userinput of anykind, it's basically update the state of our DB to our AD server, and I'm Trying to use TPL to make it faster. I THINK i've figured it out, an instance of a non thread safe class library for ad is getting spawned in the constructor... Thus causing the problem 'invisibly'. I'm refactoring now.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell, because based on the code that you've posted, it's impossible to tell where your listener might be getting called.  However, one issue that you do have is here:

```
public class SpnCustomListener:TextWriterTraceListener
{
    private INetLog log = ObjectFactory.GetInstance< INetLog >();

    private Object slLock = new Object();

    private List <string> sl = null;
```

Because your `slLock` object is private, it will be created per instance of the class, and so it won't work across threads; try this:

```
public class SpnCustomListener:TextWriterTraceListener
{
    private INetLog log = ObjectFactory.GetInstance< INetLog >();

    private static Object slLock = new Object();

    private List <string> sl = null;
```